# How the financial sense of "capitale" derived from the adjective "capitale" as something which has to do with head?

Tags: etymology

Unlike Ayto below, [Etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/word/capital#etymonline_v_53180) doesn't mention any Italian etymons for the English "capital" meaning wealth.

> #### capital [13]

> Etymologically, *capital* is
> something that is at the top or ‘head’; it comes
> from Latin *caput* ‘head’. The various current
> English uses of the word reached us, however, by
> differing routes. The first to come was the
> adjective, which originally meant simply ‘of the
> head’ (Milton in *Paradise lost* wrote of the
> Serpent’s ‘capital bruise’, meaning the bruise to
> its head); this came via Old French *capital* from
> Latin *capitālis*, a derivative of *caput*. The other
> senses of the adjective have derived from this:
> ‘capital punishment’, for instance, comes from
> the notion of a crime which, figuratively
> speaking, affects the head, or life. Its use as a
> noun dates from the 17th century: **the immediate
> source of the financial sense is Italian *capitale***. The architectural *capital* ‘top of a column’ (as in
> ‘Corinthian capitals’) also comes from Latin
> *caput*, but in this case the intermediate form was
> the diminutive *capitellum* ‘little head’, which
> reached English in the 14th century via Old
> French *capitel*.

*Word Origins* (2005 2e) by John Ayto. p 92 Right column.

Why "capitale" started to have the finance related meaning it has in Italian?

Comment: Welcome to ItalianSE!

Comment: They say that “capital” in the financial sense derives from the Italian term “capitale.” Probably because the first bank was created in Florence, Italy. Are you asking about the etymology of “capitale”?

Comment: According to Etymonline : Capital; *1610s, "a person's wealth," from Medieval Latin capitale "stock, property," noun use of neuter of Latin capitalis "capital, chief, first".*

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it asks about the origin of an English word, so it's off topic here. It might be more suitable for one of the English language SEs.

Comment: @DaG:  I've changed the title of the question in such a way that it doesn't seem off-topic in this site (from the beginning, I've interpreted this question in this way).

Comment: @Charo: But the text of the question explicitly mentions “etymons” for an English word and two works about English etymology. I wouldn't encourage such off-topic questions.

Comment: @DaG I partly disagree. The question might be clearer about it, but the bulk is “why *capitale* started to have the finance related meaning it has in Italian?”

Comment: @egreg: It might well be, or perhaps something else altogether. At it stands, it's anybody guess what it's asking, since there is no question in the body, the old title was unclear and has since been changed by Charo (I understand her good-willing intervention, but nothing in the question is related to the present title; if anything, part of it declares that Italian has nothing to do with it: “Etymonline doesn't mention any Italian etymons”). the fact is: 4 people suggest that it is off-topic or unclear. Why is it still there? How do closure and deletion work?

Comment: @DaG Five closing votes are needed.

Comment: @egreg Bene, grazie.

Comment: @DaG About this kind of nonblatant off-topic, I prefer to consider myself as a normal user.

Comment: @bfly: Can you please clarify what you are asking about? Because if it's the etymology of Italian "capitale" with a financial sense, the question is on-topic; but if it's something about English "capital",  then it would be off-topic on this site.

Comment: @Charo Egreg is correct. " the bulk is “why capitale started to have the finance related meaning it has in Italian?”" That's my question.

Comment: OK, @bfly: I've edited your post so that the body includes this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have found in the dictionary, the adjective *capitale* means something which has to do with  head, considered the main part of a body,
as explained by [Treccani dictionary](https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/capo)

> in quanto il capo, cioè la testa, è la parte principale e più nobile del corpo

This is the definition of the adjective *capitale* from [*Grande dizionario della lingua italiana*](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI02/00000691.jpg):

> Che riguarda il capo, la vita di una persona (*pena, sentenza, supplizio, peri­colo capitale*)

From this, the following [figurative meaning](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI02/00000621.jpg) arised:

> Principale, essenziale, di fondamen­tale importanza.

I.e., it's an adjective used to qualify something essential or of great importance. For instance, the most important city of a region or state is called "la città capitale" or simply "la capitale".

The first attested use of the noun  [*capitale*](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI02/00000691.jpg) with a financial sense is this sentence coming from the [*Testi fiorentini*](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI_indice_autori/00284.jpg), a collection of tests from 1211 to 1313:

> S’elli non pagasse, sì no promise di pagare Orlandino Galigaio prode e capitale quant’elli istessero.

According to *Grande dizionario della lingua italiana*, the meaning of *capitale* in this sentence is

> La parte principale di un patrimonio in denaro: rispetto alla somma mi­nore costituita dagli interessi che essa produce.

That is,

> The main part of a money asset compared to the lesser amount constituted by the interest it produces.

The idea is that this "capitale" is the  main part of an amount of money in the same way that the head is considered to be the main  part of a body.